# How do I fix the 'Specified cast is not valid' error?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a Key Binder which gets keys from the keyboard and binds them to certain actions for my program. The problem is that when I try to actually bind the keys to a certain action, it is not working as intended. It errors out with the 'Specified cast is not valid.' error message.
Also, here is the code, so you could have more of a chance to fix my problem:

```
        private void keyBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((TextBox)sender).Tag.ToString() == "keydect")
            {
                string ctrl = KeyToString("CTRL+", e.Control).ToString();
                string alt = KeyToString("ALT+", e.Alt).ToString();
                string shft = KeyToString("SHFT+", e.Shift).ToString();
                string key = NotIncludeKeyMod(e.KeyCode.ToString());
                Keys keys = ((Keys)KeyToString(Keys.ControlKey, e.Control)) | ((Keys)KeyToString(Keys.Menu, e.Alt)) | ((Keys)KeyToString(Keys.ShiftKey, e.Shift)) | e.KeyCode;
                ((TextBox)sender).Text = ctrl + alt + shft + key;
                if (((TextBox)sender).Name == "startClick")
                {
                    startClickingToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = keys;
                }
                else if (((TextBox)sender).Name == "stopClick")
                {
                    stopClickingToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = keys;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is also the function for KeyToString, if it has anything to do with this:

```
        private object KeyToString(object key, bool include)
        {
            if (include)
            {
                return key;
            }
            return "";
        }
```

I tried putting the multiple keys in a separate variable, but it did not work. It still resulted in the same problem. What I was expecting was for it to bind the keys to the action, but it still errored out.
What I did realize though is that the whole thing containing the different keys was making the bug happen in the first place, it was not the ShortcutKeys property or anything like that.

If you know how to fix this problem, please answer.
Thanks.

Comment: `KeyToString` returns a `Key` if `include` is `true` and a `string` if `include` is `false`. You cannot cast a `string` to a `Key`.  It's not clear to me at all what you're trying to do to suggest something better, but that's the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Key from some input string, try:

```
  private Keys KeyToString(string keyString)
    {
        if (Enum.TryParse(keyString, out Keys key))
        {
            return key;
        }
        else
        {
            return Keys.None;
        }
    }
```

From Microsoft help page, a combination of keys is simply | together like this:

```
printToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.P;
```

for Ctrl + P
[ToolStripShortcutKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeys?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)